# Is Hyperledger Besu compatible with Cosmos IBC?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-besu

I am beginning a project that uses Hyperledger Besu as its underlying blockchain and looking ahead to interoperability and cross-shard functionalities.

There are a number of 'internet-of-blockchain' projects (including Polkadot and Hyperledger Cactus), but I am particularly interested in Cosmos and the Inter-blockchain communication (IBC) model.

My question is about the compatibility of Besu with Cosmos IBC. [In most sources](https://v1.cosmos.network/intro), IBC is said to be compatible with any blockchain that offers non-probabilistic consensus. Besu satisfies this when instantiated with, say, IBFT 2.0. [Other documentation](https://ibcprotocol.org/faq/) (see section "What Blockchains are compatible with IBC?") gives a more significant list of requirements.

I do not know enough about Besu or the requirements linked to above to evaluate whether Besu can interoperate with IBC.

*Is there a simple answer to whether Besu is compatible with IBC?*

*If not, what aspects of a Besu-based project will influence compatibility?*

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

IBC-Solidity, the IBC implementations in Solidity, enables EVM-compatible blockchains, including Hyperledger Besu, to be interoperable via Cosmos IBC.

https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/yui-ibc-solidity

IBC Solidity is one of the components of YUI, a Hyperledger Lab, that archives interoperability with multiple heterogeneous blockchains through Cosmos IBC.